# Autoscaling policy brings up the wrong number of instances. 

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I configured an autoscaling policy to bring up 8 instances, but it won't bring up more than 2.

Here's a description of the policy from AWS:

```
bash# /opt/aws/apitools/as/bin/as-describe-policies
SCALING-POLICY  mygroup  Up         8   ExactCapacity  5  arn:aws:autoscaling:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxx:scalingPolicy:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:autoScalingGroupName/mygroup:policyName/Up
```

I call the policy like this:

```
bash# /opt/aws/apitools/as/bin/as-execute-policy Up --auto-scaling-group mygroup
```

Looking at the scaling activity confirms what I see: it only tries to bring up 2 instances:

```
bash# /opt/aws/apitools/as/bin/as-describe-scaling-activities  --auto-scaling-group mygroup --show-xml

<AutoScalingGroupName>mygroup</AutoScalingGroupName>
    <Cause>At 2012-06-05T17:05:25Z a user request executed policy Up changing the desired capacity from 0 to 2.  At 2012-06-05T17:05:37Z an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from 0 to 2.</Cause>
```

There are no errors in the output of as-describe-scaling-activities. I have only one autoscaling group right now.

Any clues as to what I might be doing wrong? I've deleted/recreated/renamed the group, the policies and the launch config, but I never see more than 2 instances.

Comment: can you do describe-group and add that? What is the max defined in the group?